# Javascript function is not working on asp:button Click event, where a test alert function works.!

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am trying to create an alert as described in this site http://needim.github.com/noty/
and here is the code

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttons.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="customContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function generate(type, layout) {
            var n = noty({
                theme: 'defaultTheme',
                text: 'Do you want to continue?',
                buttons: [
    {
        addClass: 'btn btn-primary',
        text: 'Ok',
        onClick: function ($noty) {
            // this = button element
            // $noty = $noty element
            $noty.close();
            noty(
            {
                text: 'Record deleted !',
                type: 'success',
                callback:
                {
                    onShow: function () { },
                    afterShow: function () { TakeValue(true); },
                    onClose: function () {  },
                    afterClose: function () { }
                }
            });
        }
    },
     {
         addClass: 'btn btn-danger',
         text: 'Cancel',
         onClick: function ($noty) {
             $noty.close();
             noty(
            {
                text: 'Record not deleted !',
                type: 'warning',
                callback:
                 {
                     onShow: function () { },
                     afterShow: function () { TakeValue(false); },
                     onClose: function () { },
                     afterClose: function () { }
                 }
            });
         }
     }
    ]

            });

        }
     function TakeValue(result) {
            if (result == true) {
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = "true";
                alert(document.getElementById("Hidden1").value);

            } else {

                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = "false";
                alert(document.getElementById("Hidden1").value);
            }
        }
        function generateAll() {
            generate('information', 'top');
        }

    </script>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="false"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Press"  OnClientClick="return generateAll();" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="return generateAll();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I have placed two buttons ,one is HTML button while the other is of asp:Button,
The whole scenario just works fine when I use the HTML button ,but the page is not displaying the similar behavior in case of asp:Button click, I have placed a test function in JavaScript to test the OnClientClick event of the asp:Button and that worked fine,but I don't know why this alert is not getting called, I think there is some problem with the Noty JS.
Kindly give feed back

thanks.

Comment: an `asp:button` will cause a postback when clicked by default. you need to return false from the `onclientclick`, right now you are returning `undefined` since `generateAll` has no return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jbabey said in the comments:

> an asp:button will cause a postback when clicked by default. you need to `return false` from the onclientclick, right now you are returning undefined since generateAll has no return.

Since you're using jQuery, I'd go one step further and not directly set the `click` attribute. Instead, set it using jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Button1').click(generateAll);
});
...
function generateAll(e) {
    generate('information', 'top');
    // This will prevent the default action of submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing really happend ,in webdev toolbar  it says e is undefined :((

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add UseSubmitBehavior="false" attribute to the asp:button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Press" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return generateAll();" />
```

I hope this will resolve your issue. Please let me know whether it helped you or not.